# with knockout and a json list how do i display a checkbox for each item in list then only display it if checked

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

here is a not working version:

```
 <div data-bind="template: {name: 'checkbox-template', foreach: timeframes}"></div>

        <script type="text/html" id="checkbox-template">
            <div><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $data, attr: {value: $data}" /><div data-bind="text: $data"></div></div>
        </script>


        <p>In bar format:</p>
        <canvas class="graph" id="overallBarChart"></canvas>


        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'stat-template', foreach: statsDisplay }"></div>

        <script type="text/html" id="stat-template">
            <h3 data-bind="text: chartname"></h3>
            <div style="height:300px"><canvas class="graph" data-bind="attr: {id: chartname}"></canvas></div>
        </script>

        <script>
             statistics = JSON.parse('{"Intimacy": {"03/09/2020": 1.0, "02/10/2020": 4.0, "04/11/2020": 7.0}, "Community": {"03/09/2020": 2.0, "02/10/2020": 4.0, "04/11/2020": 2.0}}');
            function AppViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.stats = ko.observableArray([]);
                Object.keys(statistics).forEach(function(key) {
                    self.stats.push({chartname: key, datesAndValues: statistics[key]});
                });
                console.log(self.stats());
                self.timeframes=ko.observableArray([]);
                console.log("timeframes before")
                console.log(self.timeframes());
                self.statsDisplay = ko.observableArray();
                self.sd = self.timeframes.subscribe(function(timeframes){
                    out=[];
                    console.log("running subscribe")
                    console.log(self.stats())
                    for (category in Object.keys(self.stats())){
                        out[category]= {};
                        out[category]["chartname"] = self.stats()[category]["chartname"];
                        out[category]["datesAndValues"] = {};
                    }
                    for (category in Object.keys(self.stats())){
                        for (time in self.timeframes()){
                            out[category]["datesAndValues"][time]={}
                        }
                    }
                    for (category in self.stats()){
                        cat=category
                        category=self.stats()[category]
                        console.log("in last cat loop")
                        console.log(cat)
                        console.log(category)
                        for (stattime in category["datesAndValues"]){
                            console.log("stattiem loop")
                            console.log(stattime)
                            for (tftime in self.timeframes()){
                                tftime=self.timeframes()[tftime]
                                console.log("various inside timeframes loop")
                                console.log(tftime)
                                console.log(stattime)
                                if (tftime === stattime){
                                    console.log("slkdnsndclskdn")
                                    console.log(category["datesAndValues"][tftime])
                                    out[cat]["datesAndValues"][tftime] = self.stats()[cat]["datesAndValues"][tftime]
                                };
                            };
                        };
                    };
                    console.log(out)
                    self.statsDisplay(out);
                }, null, 'arrayChange');
                Object.keys(self.stats()[0]["datesAndValues"]).forEach(function (key){
                    self.timeframes.push(key);
                });
            };

            var st = new AppViewModel();

            ko.applyBindings(st);
```

Im trying to display only the dates selected in a checkbox and i keep falling down because the for loops seem to randomly return either a number or the key for the object.

My logic was to loop through and compare the times in the statistics with the times in the timeframes var into a new observable on a subscribe to the timeframes witch gets populated on load and would change on select.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the joys of working with Knockout and nested objects...

What you could do in this case is have two variables on your view model: one that holds all of the data, and one that holds just the selected data. Since you're working with objects, you'd need to add some logic that populates the "selected data" variable with the correct keys.

```
function ViewModel() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.statistics = ko.observable({});
  vm.selectedStatistics = ko.observable({});
  
  vm.init = function () {
    // This is our data; it probably comes from an API
    const statistics = JSON.parse('{"Intimacy": {"03/09/2020": 1.0, "02/10/2020": 4.0, "04/11/2020": 7.0}, "Community": {"03/09/2020": 2.0, "02/10/2020": 4.0, "04/11/2020": 2.0}}');

    // We have to add the keys to selectedStatistics
    // There, we store the selected values in an observableArray
    const stats = Object.keys(statistics);
    let i = stats.length;
    while (i--) {
        const selected = vm.selectedStatistics();
        selected[stats[i]] = ko.observableArray();
        vm.selectedStatistics(selected);
    }
    
    vm.statistics(statistics);
  }
  
  vm.init();
}
```

And this will show your checkboxes and selected checkboxes:

```
<h3>
 Statistics
</h3>

<!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(statistics()), as: 'stat' } -->
<h4 data-bind="text: stat"></h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: Object.keys($parent.statistics()[stat])">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parents[1].selectedStatistics()[stat], checkedValue: $data, attr: { id: [stat, $index()].join('-')  }">
    <label data-bind="text: $data + ': ' + $parents[1].statistics()[stat][$data], attr: { for: [stat, $index()].join('-') }"></label>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->

<h3>
Selected statistics
</h3>
<!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(selectedStatistics()), as: 'stat' } -->
<h4 data-bind="text: stat"></h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: $parent.selectedStatistics()[stat]">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/Ljwxduv0/

Comment: Thanks for the response! doesnt this mean that the selected checkboxes will not update the init function when selected or deselected though? I've so far moved to doing it serverside, but with some advice i might move back.

Comment: No. The `checked` binding will take care of updating the `selectedStatistics` variable when the checkboxes are checked/unchecked, as you can see in the Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you! I will have another shot at this bearing in mind your answer.